# Limiting the <li> items to 7 items while retaining the first and last <li>

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have to limit the items to 5 items but the first and last item should still display on top and bottom of the list.
I tried setting the height to fixed size of 7 items(5 items plus the first and last item) and inserting scroll bar for overflow but the problem is, the last item which should be on the bottom part is hidden.
Here is my HTML code:

```
 <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                        <a href="javascript:;"
                                           data-toggle="dropdown">
                                           <img th:src="@{/resources/images/completion/design/add_geomechanics.png}" width="15" height="15" alt="...">
                                            <span>Add Geomechanics</span>
                                        </a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="left: -245px">
                                            <li v-if="mseConfig.length > 0">
                                                <a href="javascript:;">
                                                    Select Geomechanics Configuration
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li v-for="(config, index) in mseConfig" v-bind:class="config.isSelected ? 'applied-mse-config' : ''"  style="position: relative;">
                                                <a href="javascript:;" v-bind:class="config.isSelected ? 'mse-config-design-anchor-white-color' : 'mse-config-design-anchor-black-color'" id="mse-config-design-anchor" v-on:click="configureMSE(config)">
                                                     - {{config.title}}
                                                    <i  class="icon-trash mse-config-design-trash"
                                                        v-on:click.stop="deleteMSEConfig(config, index)">
                                                    </i>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li style="border-top: 1px solid #d1e0ea;">
                                                <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mdlSEMCreatePallete">
                                                   Create Geomechanics Configuration
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
```

I want the list to be like on the photo with only the middle items are scrollable and only shows 5 items. [image: View Image]

Comment: Hey could you please share full code to replicate the issue, or a jsfiddle/codepen to show the issue, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try by making the scrollbars invisible. You can still scroll though.

```
.dropdown-menu::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already solved it. i placed <li v-for="(config, index) in mseConfig" v-bind:class="config.isSelected ? 'applied-mse-config' : ''"  style="position: relative;"> into another div, set the max-height and overflow-y: scroll. and adjusted the css because the style got messed up